# R ggplot2 connecting points NOT by x-axis but by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I'm having a data.frame extracted from vegan metaMDS which looks like this:

```
    MDS1         MDS2 time nucleic_acid habitat treatment
10dnawatercontrol  0.06297458  0.153364604   10          dna   water   control
10dnawatertreated   -0.20010385 -0.241614081   10          dna   water     treated
11dnawatercontrol  0.15518683  0.067861388   11          dna   water   control
11dnawatertreated   -0.12137470 -0.258434255   11          dna   water     treated
12dnawatercontrol -0.02041011  0.140458063   12          dna   water   control
12dnawatertreated   -0.36101682 -0.110667764   12          dna   water     treated
13dnawatercontrol -0.19054474  0.287597321   13          dna   water   control
13dnawatertreated   -0.26751484 -0.092326331   13          dna   water     treated
14dnawatercontrol -0.10942501  0.208263588   14          dna   water   control
14dnawatertreated   -0.33594573  0.015625565   14          dna   water     treated
15dnawatercontrol -0.06631137  0.226240078   15          dna   water   control
15dnawatertreated   -0.27606083 -0.019999889   15          dna   water     treated
16dnawatercontrol  0.01703248  0.132900239   16          dna   water   control
16dnawatertreated   -0.32565421 -0.022154859   16          dna   water     treated
17dnawatercontrol -0.25806806  0.201731201   17          dna   water   control
17dnawatertreated   -0.40662186 -0.003830044   17          dna   water     treated
18dnawatercontrol -0.17699110  0.184587876   18          dna   water   control
18dnawatertreated   -0.46597548 -0.022633769   18          dna   water     treated
19dnawatercontrol -0.28119311  0.197837800   19          dna   water   control
19dnawatertreated   -0.62468238  0.187704606   19          dna   water     treated
4dnawatercontrol   1.23658067  0.660553669    4          dna   water   control
4dnawatertreated     0.85195731 -0.740790358    4          dna   water     treated
5dnawatercontrol   0.66159385  0.183955243    5          dna   water   control
5dnawatertreated     0.36367763 -0.446656965    5          dna   water     treated
6dnawatercontrol   0.19736034  0.206992740    6          dna   water   control
6dnawatertreated    -0.04189317 -0.273487207    6          dna   water     treated
7dnawatercontrol   0.35362061 -0.005658852    7          dna   water   control
7dnawatertreated     0.14481323 -0.409432041    7          dna   water     treated
8dnawatercontrol   0.30718548  0.072991390    8          dna   water   control
8dnawatertreated     0.13210812 -0.311147579    8          dna   water     treated
9dnawatercontrol   0.20028730  0.065109821    9          dna   water   control
9dnawatertreated    -0.15459106 -0.234941197    9          dna   water     treated
```

and I'm plotting this data with ggplot2:

```
ggplot()+ 
geom_point(data=meta_nmds_water_dna,aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,shape=treatment,colour=time),size=3)+
geom_line(data=meta_nmds_water_dna,aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,group=treatment,colour=time),size=1)+
geom_text(data=meta_nmds_water_dna,aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,label=time,size=6,vjust=0))
```

[image: nmds]

as you can see, the geom_points are connected according to the x values, but I want to have them connected via the "time"-factor, do you know a way for doing this?

Comment: see `?geom_path`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: do you want something like this `geom_line(data=meta_nmds_water_dna,aes(x=MDS1, y=MDS2 , group=time, colour=time), size=1)` ?

Comment: Make sure you add `coord_equal` or the ordination will be incorrectly scaled. Also, better to put the common data/aesthetics into the `ggplot()` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah perfect Ben, thanks for pushing me in the right direction! With:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=meta_nmds_water_dna,aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,shape=treatment,colour=time),size=4) +
  geom_path(data=path,aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,group=treatment,colour=as.numeric(as.character(time))),size=1.5)+
  geom_text(data=meta_nmds_water_dna,aes(x=MDS1,y=MDS2,label=time,size=5,vjust=-0.7)) +
  coord_equal()
```

I got exactly what I wanted. Make sure you have your data in the right order, though:

```
path<-meta_nmds_water_dna
path$time<-as.numeric(as.character(path$time))
path<-path[order(path$time),]
```

[image: nmds2_geom_path]